# How to declare a function as a variable in Kotlin

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin, listener

So I am trying to create a listener in Kotlin. I just want to pass a method that will be executed latter in my code. Like this:

```
override fun setButtonClickListener(listener: (text: String) -> Unit) {
    this.listener = listener
}
```

But, when I declare my listener, I must declare it like this:

```
private var listener : (text: String) -> Unit = null!!
```

Otherwise my AS will complain. But this !! in a null object seams so weird. How should I declare this listener??

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

there many ways to declare a function as a variable in kotlin.

you can using [lateinit properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) to initializing the property in later, for example:

```
private lateinit var listener : (text: String) -> Unit
```

**OR** make the `listener` nullable, but  you must call it with [safe-call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls): `listener?.handle(...)` in this way:

```
private var listener : ((text: String) -> Unit)? = null
```

**OR** declare it with a empty lambda to avoiding NPException, for example:

```
private var listener : (String) -> Unit = {}
```

**OR** declare a private function, and then you can reference it by [function reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references), for example:

```
private var listener = this::handle

private fun handle(text:String) = TODO()
```

*Note*: when you declare a function variable, the parameter name is optional, for example:

```
private var listener : (text:String) -> Unit = TODO()
//                      |--- parameter name is omitted
private var listener : (String) -> Unit = TODO()
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time I forget how to do this I end up with this answer, but it's not exactly what I need, so if you are looking for a way to create a function that generates some code into your function it would look like this

```
val createMock: (String, Int, Int, Boolean) -> MyMockType =
    { language: String, major: Int, minor: Int, published: Boolean ->
        MyMockObject(
            language = language,
            majorVersion = major,
            minorVersion = minor,
            published = published,
            content = "",
            createdAt = Timestamp(12345000)
        )
    }

val englishMock = createMock("en", 1, 0, true)
val portuguesMock = createMock("pt-BR", 1, 0, true)
```